# How to write emojis in PDF using apache pdfBox?

Tags: pdfbox

I want to write text along with emojis in pdf using pdfBox. Text is working properly written in pdf but emojis were missing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using a font that contains the right chars?  Emoji aren't anything particularly special, other than having really high Unicode numbers

Comment: Thank you Mike ..I used helvetica bold font first that didn't work so i tried with several multiple fonts but the issue is same. Do you know any specific font that support emoji unicode?

Comment: Try a current truetype font from your PC, not the "standard 14" type 1 fonts from PDFBox. Note that these won't be the colorful emojis from your mobile device, they'll be single color.

Comment: Try things out in a word processor first - much quicker than via PDFbox

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.